# Function keeps crashing without error message

Tags: c, function, crash

Hello I am taking an intro to C-programming class so I am using very basic codes. Here I am simply trying to get a matrix of the commas out of the main string. However when I try running the program it keeps crashing on me and I don't know what is my problem. I was able to use the fgets function correctly so I think that is working fine still.

**CD Data.txt File**

```
Eagles, Hotel California, 1976, Rock, 4
The Fratellis, Costello Music, 2006, Garage Rock, 5
Awolnation, Megalithic Symphony, 2011, Indie Rock, 5
Lindsey Stirling, Lindsey Stirling, 2012, Classical Crossover, 5
Arctic Monkeys, AM, 2013, Indie Rock, 4
```

**Program**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define row 1000
#define column 1000

void getCommas(char str[], int commas[])
{
    int flag, count, index;

    count = 0;
    index = 0;
    flag = 1;
    while(flag = 1)
    {
        if(str[count] = ',')
        {
            commas[index] = count;
            index = index + 1;
        }
        count = count + 1;

        if(str[count] = '\0')
        {
            flag = 0;
        }
    }

}

int main()
{
    int i;

    char CdInfo[row][column];
    int Index[row][column];

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("CD Data.txt","r");

    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        fgets(CdInfo[i], sizeof CdInfo, fp);
        //printf("%s\n",CdInfo[i]);
    }

    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        getCommas(CdInfo[i], Index[i]);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To begin with, change this `if(str[count] = ',')` to this `if(str[count] == ',')` and this `if(str[count] = '\0')` to this `if(str[count] == '\0')`.

Comment: In addition, change `fgets(CdInfo[i], sizeof CdInfo, fp)` to `fgets(CdInfo[i], sizeof CdInfo[i], fp)`

Comment: Thanks barak! That helped tremendously, but if i change CdInfo to CdInfo[i] it's not giving me what I want, CdInfo, like it is, is working fine.

Comment: All of this implies that you either have an extremely bad compiler (even worse than Turbo C from 1990 which would produce warnings for this code) or, far more likely, you have basic compiler warnings disabled.

Comment: Is there a reset button or default settings? I barely know how to work CodeBlocks, I haven't gone into the settings once. The language there is giberish to me.

Comment: if you had written each of the conditionals, like using: while(1 = flag) instead of while(flag = 1) I.E. put the literal on the left side in conditionals.  Then the compiler would have caught many of your coding errors.  As it is, '=' is an assignment while '==' is a comparison.  so use '===' when making comparisons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two variables are too big to be on the stack:

```
int main()
{
    int i;

    char CdInfo[row][column]; //<<
    int Index[row][column];   //<<
```

declare them as static or as global variables.

And:

```
while(flag = 1)
```

should be

```
while(flag == 1)
```

and all

```
if (str[count] = ...
```

should be

```
if(str[count] == ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am usually better about getting those double == signs, it's too early maybe. And I did shrink down the column and now it works, not sure I understand why it didn't work before. I thought you had plenty of memory space to work with.

I do have one more question now though, commas[0]=9, commas[1]=13, commas[2]=19, commas[3]=31, it's giving me not what I want, what is it doing here?

Comment: @Maty sorry, I didn't understand the last sentence of of your comment. Maybe you should post a new question with that specific problem.

Comment: I tried but have to wait 90 minutes. I printed the array commas[], from the function, and these are the results that I got. commas[0]=9, commas[1]=13, commas[2]=19. commas[3]=31.

Comment: @Maty : wait 90 minutes ? For which input do you get this result ? I think it's best if you post a new question.

Comment: Ok, I'll just post it in a new question. It says I can only post once every 90 minutes. Thanks for your time though, I'll wait it out and try to figure out while I wait.

Answer (score 0):

You should also think about replacing

```
while(flag = 1) {
```

with :

```
while(flag == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// note:
// the code is not making any use of more than one line of the
// input file at any one time, so
// only the current row actually needs to be defined

// note:
// this code makes no check for max length of each row (1000 char)
// that could/will be a problem when the input line is longer than 1000 character

// to avoid the error of writing an assignment rather than a literal,
// place the literal on the left side, 
// then the compiler will notify you of the error
// rather than you having to spend time debugging the code
// trying to find the error

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define row 1000
#define column 1000

//void getCommas(char str[], int commas[])
void getCommas( char * pStr, int * pCommas )
{
    //int flag, count, index;

    //count = 0;
    //index = 0;
    //flag = 1;
    int flag = 1;
    int count = 0;
    int index = 0;

    //while(flag = 1)
    // following while loop could eliminate 
    // the 'flag' variable and related code by using
    // and would be safer because never looking at string termination
    // character but once.
    // while( '\0' != pStr[count] )
    while( 1 == flag )
    {
        //if(str[count] = ',')
        if( ',' == pStr[count] )
        {
            pCommas[index] = count;
            index = index + 1;
        }
        count = count + 1;

        //if(str[count] = '\0')
        if( '\0' == pStr[count] )
        { // then found end of string
            flag = 0;
        }
    }
}

char CdInfo[row][column];
int Index[row][column];

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int rowCount = 0;

    //char CdInfo[row][column]; // this is a huge item on the stack, 
    //int Index[row][column]; // this is a huge item on the stack, 

    //FILE *fp;
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    fp = fopen("CD Data.txt","r");

    // always check the result of calls to io functions
    if ( NULL == fp )
    { // then fopen failed
        perror( "fopen" );
        exit(1);
    }

    // implied else

    // there is no reasonable reason (in the real world) 
    // to expect the input to be only 5 lines
    //for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    //{
    //    fgets(CdInfo[i], sizeof CdInfo, fp);
    //    //printf("%s\n",CdInfo[i]);
    //}
    for( i=0; i<row; i++ )
    {
        // following line checks results of call to I/O function 
        if( 0 == fgets( CdInfo[i], row, fp ) ) { break; }
        // above line exits loop on end of file or I/O error
        rowCount++;
    }

    //for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    for( i = 0; i < rowCount; i++ )
    {
        getCommas(CdInfo[i], Index[i]);
    }


    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```